# Cannot download file from Django under local dev mode

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to download a file from Django under local development mode. I tried to follow lots of Stackoverflow posts and here is my code of doing so.

```
class AutoPushView(View):
    def get(self, request, eventId):
        fileName = '/Users/tommy/DjangoProject/mysite/static/python.png'
        mimeType, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(fileName)
        response = HttpResponse(open(fileName, 'rb'), content_type=mimeType)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % os.path.basename(fileName)
        return response
```

And I have my urls.py and settings.py as following

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:eventId>/autopush', views.AutoPushView.as_view(), name='autopush'),
]
```

```
# settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/Users/lbc/DjangoProject/mysite/static/',
]
```

When I invoke the view from a browser (press a HTML button), there's no error shown but the download action is not triggered. What am I missing here?

Comment: What debugging are you able to do? e.g. have you put a `print()` in there to verify that the `get()` is called?

Comment: @markwalker_ Yes I did print out the response and the headers that I specified in it. The status code looks good. I also tried to changed the `content_type` to `application/force-download` but still no luck.